# What type of queries are considered as SQL injection?

Tags: postgresql, security, sql-injection

I was testing efficacy of a paid **Database security solution** which has the ability to detect and block **SQLi attack**. For the testing purpose I have tried the following query against a **PostgreSQL** database through this tool which act as a proxy.

`select * from test where id=1 or 1=1;`

For this query the tool were able to detect and block. But then I tried another one

`select * from test where id=1 or true;`

But this time the query got infiltrated and got the full table data as result.

Isn't it a classical example of SQLi? What type of queries are actually considered as SQLi which I can test against the tool?

Comment: The typical SQL injection query contains at least four single quotes, because it works by interpolating a string between single quotes. I would be very wary of any tool that claims to recognize such queries. It will either miss some statements or report false positives or both.

Comment: IMO,  double hyphen `--` somewhere in the middle of the query could be a sign of sql injection, especially if the part have been commented out contains something similar to sql, the semicolon `;` could be a sign of sql injection as well.

Comment: Why would you use statements like that and not filter/clean out user input ?  If you really want to be sure then use only stored procedures for data access.

Comment: If that is what you want to protect against, then you have already done the test and the tool failed.  What more do you need to know?

Comment: @jjanes i am trying to understand different type of SQLi queries that supposed to detect as a threat so i can test the tool for it's accuracy. Since the 2nd one is failed I having a doubt whether it's not a valid SQLi or this tool not just good for Postgres bcoz that statement will not work for MSSQL.

Comment: @BasilTitus the task of proving that particular SQL query is malicious seems to be hard, for example, in your case `or 1=1` looks suspicious from tool's perspective, however it fails on PostgreSQL grammar where `or true` is valid statement, the problem is there is a zillion of options to write "always true statement", does your tool recognise something like `or exists (select * from pg_class)` for example? IMO, the tool should have built-in SQL engine in order to be able to detect anomalies in SQL queries, that is definitely much simpler to develop PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Yes I understand, is there any existing extension exists for the same?

Answer (score 0):

This *isn't* a Sql Injection attack.
*This* is: (obligatory XKCD Reference) "[Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)".

I'm not entirely sure what *this* is trying to protect against ...

```
... or 1 = 1 ...
```

I've seen several Management Information applications that build dynamic Sql where clauses using exactly this construct (and then appending other, 'and'ed conditions after it).

```
where 1 = 1 
and ... 
and ...
```

Lazy coding, but quick and easy.

If Row-Based security is done properly, this wouldn't gain the attacker anyway because they would only gain access to all of the rows that they were allowed to see anyway - effectively, all SQL runs against an already-filtered dataset.

Comment: I bet the given example of sql injection query was based on [SQL Injection from OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)

Comment: The `1 = 1;` (notice the semicolon terminator) is a common pattern used *with* SQL injections (at least many moons ago, idk what's commonplace anymore) as a way to cleanly terminate the orginal valid SQL statement with a valid clause, so that then additional SQL statements could be injected directly after without breaking the original SQL statement from a bad syntax error, ensuring the injected commands ran successfully. I imagine whatever tool OP is using, is just blindly looking for that exact predicate, which is obviously a false positive in many cases.

Comment: You turn `WHERE id=98356` into `WHERE id=98356 or 1=1` and now you get back the entire table rather rather than the small part of it you were supposed to get back.

Comment: You can put `1=1` and `AND` together, no problem even if it's useless statement.But why would someone put  `or 1=1` at the end of a statement unless it's an attack, if i want full data i just query the table without `where` clause.